# How to best handle shared entities within Microservice using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, api, architecture, dependencies, microservices

I've got 2 microservices API called `User` and `Order`. Since these are microservices, they both have *separate* DbContext and different *unrelated* entities. One of the requirements I got is to List `Orders` with the **Name** of the `User` who ordered it.

The *simplified* entities are like this:

```
public class User
{
   public Guid UserId {get;set;}
   public string Name  {get;set;}
   //Notice no ORM relations added for Order
}

public class Order
{
   public Guid OrderId {get;set;}
   public Guid UserId {get;set}
   //Notice no ORM relations user added. ONLY UserId is returned since this is a microservice and another domain
}
```

Right now, I can only think of 1 efficient approach but still has it cons

Retrieve Orders and send ALL UserId's to User microservice to a method like below:

```
public ICollection<Tuple<Guid,string> GetUserNames(ICollection<Guid> userIds)
{
   //go to the database with ORM and get userId and username as a list
}
```

With my approach, it does not seem practical since someday later, the requirement can change and User's Gender or any other information might additionally be required. I'd then have to write many methods for that specific requirements or change my code every time. 
Also, retrieving **ALL** info of the `user` everytime is not practical as well since it will consume much network traffic.

Is there such best practice to handle shared entities better than I have in mind? Or, do you think this approach is still good enough?

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to change the signature of some API to add gender in the future, I think it is an exaggeration when you say you will have to change many methods. You could use GraphQL to make your API queryable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose one of the following based on a clear separation of concerns. Definitely have the user service only be responsible for any inquiries about users and the order service be responsible about inquiries about orders. Now you can either:

1. Have the client side inquire about User ID(s) for User Names first, before sending the inquiry about Orders with User IDs instead of Names. This is probably the simplest solution but makes your client a bit heavier on business logic.
2. Make the Order service dependent on the User service. So the Order service gets the inquiry about orders by users Names and then the Order service asks the User service for which User IDs are those first, before fetching the Orders internally.
3. Introduce a third business service which is responsible for complex domain inquiries and breaking those into requests to your specialized services. E.g. send the original inquiry to this service, which then inquires the user service for IDs from Names and uses those to inquire Orders by Ids from the order service. Sometimes architects would chose to include such logic in custom API Gateways that would then act as an aggregator.

Note that the call that I describe above in all three solutions to retrieve User ID by Name could include more information and be more of a general user search API that also allows searching by user status, age, etc.

So there are lots of options and dependent on the rest of your domain requirements and architecture one could be better than another.